# change shell of a user from /bin/false to another

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, user-accounts

I made a mistake of change the root shell to /bin/false, but when I want to change it back, I always got error

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root
[sudo] password: <input current user password>
password: <input root password>
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

Comment: ...the easiest thing to do would be to boot off a livecd. Or try single user mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the file `/etc/passwd` if chsh doesn't work, by replacing the line

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/false
```

with

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: for editing /etc/passwd (which should indeed work) one must be root (or use sudo...). A livecd may work if the /-filesystem can be mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> sudo vigr

In the editor, change root's shell back to /bin/bash (It should be the last field on the first line)